# Show that if $\{x: f(x)\neq g(x)\}, \{x: g(x)\neq h(x)\}\in\mathfrak{M}$ then $\{x: f(x)\neq h(x)\}\in\mathfrak{M}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

**The Problem**: Show that if $\{x: f(x)\neq g(x)\}, \{x: g(x)\neq h(x)\}\in\mathfrak{M}$, then $\{x: f(x)\neq h(x)\}\in\mathfrak{M}$, where $f, g, h$ are measurable functions.

The problem arises from Walter Rudin's *Real & Complex Analysis*:
[image]

**My Question**: Obviously we can deduce that $\mu(\{x: f(x)\neq h(x)\})=0$ by the latter half of the highlighted texts; but don't we have to show that the set $\{x: f(x)\neq h(x)\}$ is indeed measurable first? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that the difference of two measurable functions is measurable? Then rewrite $$S:=\{ x\ : \ f(x)\neq g(x)\} = (f-g)^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}).$$ If $\{0\}$ is measurable, so is its complement and hence $S$ is measurable as it is the preimage of a measurable set under a measurable function.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate question?

Comment: @Gedgar If it is, please let me know which one it is then I'll vote to close the question-I failed to find the similar question.

Comment: The function $(f, g) : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable. The set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x = y\}$ is closed. So $\{\omega \in \Omega : f(\omega) = g(\omega)\}.$ is measurable.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven That makes so much more sense! But I believe you meant to say that $\{0\}$ is open (then $(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$ would be measurable).

Comment: @DickGrayson No, not open, measurable :) Singeltons are closed and thus measurable (at least if you put the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Umm... The definition of measurable function $f: X\to Y$ is that "$f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable in X for every OPEN set V in Y". Therefore, $\{0\}$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}$ (which is the $Y$ here) does not necessarily mean that its preimage is measurable.

Comment: That is a terrible definition, because for general measure spaces you do not even have a topology. The "correct" (read better) definition is that a function $f: (X, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (Y, \mathcal{B})$ is measurable if for every $S\in \mathcal{B}$ holds $f^{-1}(S)\in \mathcal{A}$, i.e. preimage of measurable sets are measurable.

Comment: Of course the "better" definition is equivalent to the one you want to use if you put the Borel sigma algebra. Still $\{0\}$ is NOT open, but it is closed. Hence, $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is open  and therefore that preimage is measurable. Now recall how preimage behave under taking complements to conclude (even with that weird definition).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven "$\mathbb{R}\\{0\}$ is open" works for the definition I have. I hope Rudin gives the more general definition later in the book like the one you have!